# Yii migration. Сменить кодировку(COLLATE) таблицы/колонки

Tags: php, yii, миграция

Как с помощью миграции сменить кодировку всей таблицы или колонки?
Например текущий `COLLATE` - `utf8_bin`, нужно сменить на `utf8_general_ci`
Для примера имя таблицы `city`, колонки: `name, region`

Comment: а что смущает? Подключаетесь к БД и делаете обычный SQL запрос типа  `ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY
    col1 VARCHAR(5)
      CHARACTER SET utf8_bin 
      COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: думал может есть вариант через Yii CDbMigration, как с alterColumn()

Answer (score -1):

```
use yii\db\Migration;

class m161123_214014_tbl_tableName extends Migration
{
    //добавляет изменения
    public function up()
    {
        $this->execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tableName` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;");
    }

    //отказ изменений
    public function down()
    {
        //echo "m161123_214014_tbl_tableName cannot be reverted.\n";
        $this->dropTable("tableName");
        return false;
    }

}
```